# Can't Share Link to Company Page from External LinkedIn Share Button

Tags: linkedin-api

I have a "share to LinkedIn button" on my website. When I share to LinkedIn the popup automatically chooses my personal account.

When try to switch to the company page I manage I get the error:

"Remove the attachment to post from another account."

When I go back, I am unable to remove the link.

Is there a way to get this button to work for my users? I'd like them to be able to use the "share to linkedin" button to share to their company page.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately this appears to be a bug / issue with LinkedIn: https://github.com/nygardk/react-share/issues/275